# Customize arrows labels in addFlows

Tags: r, r-leaflet

A am playing with arrows in `leaflet` in `R` and i found function `addFlows` in `leaflet.minicharts` library. It is exacly what I need, but I have problem to plot correct information on `popup` which we get after clicking on each arrow.
[image]

As you can see on the picture, on `popup` should be `PL to DE: 5`, unfortunately on all arrows we have `PL to LT`, it doesn't work dynamically. Is it possible to correct description? as correct I mean so that the values that make up the description come from the same line as the geographic coordinates and the value for drawing a particular arrow

Code which i used to generate pic:

```
flowArrows <- data.frame(
  out_lng = c(19, 19, 19),
  out_lat = c(52, 52, 52),
  out_iso = c("PL", "PL", "PL"),
  in_lng  = c(23, 15, 10),
  in_lat  = c(55, 49, 52),
  in_iso  = c("LT", "CZ", "DE"),
  value   = c(1, 3, 5)
)

leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldGrayCanvas) %>%
  setView(lng = 17.03097722271075, lat = 51.11043372425852, zoom = 5) %>%
  addFlows(
    flowArrows$out_lng,
    flowArrows$out_lat,
    flowArrows$in_lng,
    flowArrows$in_lat,
    flow = flowArrows$value,
    popup = popupArgs(labels = paste0(flowArrows$out_iso, " to ", flowArrows$in_iso)),
    color = "#FF0000"
  )
```